# Dockerfile: create and mount disk image during build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, mount

I am trying to build and mount a custom disk image during the Dockerfile build process:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN dd if=/dev/zero of=foo.img count=500 bs=1M
RUN mkfs.ext4 foo.img
RUN mkdir -p /media/ext4disk
RUN mount -t ext4 foo.img /media/ext4disk
```

Running `docker build`, I get the following error message on the last command: `mount failed: Unknown error -1`.

Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: I have no idea if this is even possible in a container. You could try to run the container in privileged mode `docker run --privileged`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would need the `--privileged` or `--cap-add` functionality that `docker run` does have, but that is not supported for `docker build`. So, as of current Docker version, [you can't](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1916).

See [this](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1916#issuecomment-273299742) comment:

> A significant number of docker users want the ability to --cap-add or --privileged in the build command, to mimic what is there in the run command.
>
> That's why this ticket has been open for 3 years with people constantly chiming in even though the maintainers aren't interested in giving the users what they want in this specific instance.

As an alternative you can move that `RUN` commands to a script that should run when container starts (and adding the mentioned `--privileged` flag, or `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN`)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you can now run "insecure" in build mode:

Check docs: https://github.com/docker/buildx/blob/master/README.md#--allowentitlement

```
docker buildx create --use --name insecure-builder --buildkitd-flags '--allow-insecure-entitlement security.insecure'
docker buildx build --allow security.insecure -t my-image:latest .
```

Comment: Is it supported somehow by *docker-compose*?